# How can I repay my debt or reset my bounty?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've completed the quest where you get blamed for the murders in Markarth - but now since the Dark Brotherhood quest where you need to kill the one informant about the chef I'm screwed because every time I go into Markarth the guards arrest me and I can't pay off my debt.

If I tell the guards I want to go to jail he says "you'll never see the sun again, no one escapes sindna mines", and then the dialogue box comes up with all the options again.

What should I do; never go to Markarth or just murder all the guards since I'm good at that. My debt now is probably close to 30000 coins by now.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you remember back to the first time the guards were attacking you. Had you done any questing/investigation into why the conspiracy around Markart to uncover the imprisonment of Madanach? see this [link](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/No_One_Escapes_Cidhna_Mine) possible spoiler if the answer is no to the previous

Answer (score 2):

If you agree and get sent to Sidna Mines there is a quest in there which allows you to escape. It's not very long. You will escape as part of this quest and it will also make you friends with the faction (or did for me).

I didn't lose any gear or attribute point progress.

Although I can't quite recall what quest I was on to get sent there. As a note, I've not done any Dark Brotherhood quests, mainly as I'm playing a 'goodie'.

Comment: The Sidna Mines quest is part of "Uncovering the truth around Markarth" it's not actually called that but I don't know the actual name of the quest

Comment: That where another problem is at. I submit and the guard says his lines but I'm still standing there and all of the dialogs come back.

Comment: Geez, you might have to clear your bounty with a console command then @aconaway96 if you are on PC, which seems a shame. Perhaps you've found a rare bug?

Comment: @aconaway96 there are a lot of comments around the web about exactly that. The "I surrender" and nothing happening is aparently a bug. Also [this link](http://www.ign.com/boards/threads/bug-fix-here-cidhna-mine-glitch-in-skyrim.207378921/) might fix it. I hope your not on console, most suggested fixes require console.